# Error: Expected class, delegate, enm, interface, or struct in C#

Tags: c#

Error in line : public virtual void BuyFavoriteStuff()

Error :         Expected class, delegate, enm, interface, or struct

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LearnAbstractClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }

    class Shopper 
    {
        private int TotalSpent=0, CreditLimit=10;
        public void ShopTillYouDrop()
        {
            while (TotalSpent < CreditLimit)
            BuyFavoriteStuff();
        }
    }
    public virtual void BuyFavoriteStuff() 
    {
        // No implementation here - we don’t know
        // what our student likes to buy!
    }

    class ArtStudent : Shopper 
    {
        public override void BuyFavoriteStuff() 
        {
            BuyArtSupplies();
            BuyBlackTurtlenecks();
            BuyDepressingMusic();
        }
        private void BuyBlackTurtlenecks()
        {}
        private void BuyDepressingMusic()
        {}
        private void BuyArtSupplies()
        {}
    }

    class EngineeringStudent : Shopper 
    {
        public override void BuyFavoriteStuff() 
        {
            BuyPencils();
            BuyGraphingCalculator();
            BuyPocketProtector();
        }
        private void BuyPencils()
        {}
        private void BuyGraphingCalculator()
        {}
        private void BuyPocketProtector()
        {}
    }
}
```

What is the wrong in implementation above?

Comment: Two additional things: You could make the Shopper class abstract and if you do not implement any logic, but need to have the deriving classes implement `BuyFavoriteStuff` you could mark that as abstract too without a body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your method:

```
public virtual void BuyFavoriteStuff() 
    {
        // No implementation here - we don’t know
        // what our student likes to buy!
    }
```

it outside of the Shopper class

Answer (score 4):

You have method that is outside of any class:

```
public virtual void BuyFavoriteStuff() 
{
     // No implementation here - we don’t know
     // what our student likes to buy!
}
```

just move it to `Shopper` class.

Answer (score 1):

The method `BuyFavoriteStuff` is not inside class

```
  public virtual void BuyFavoriteStuff() 
   {
    // No implementation here - we don’t know
    // what our student likes to buy!
  }
```

You should declare your method inside class.